# Foreign key reference relation does not show up after migration in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

Hie,

I have a migration in Laravel 5.5 where I have specified the foreign key reference on every tables. This works fine in my XAAMP localhost. I can see the relation in the ER diagram (working on local). As soon as i push my code to the server and migrate all my tables, the reference just dissapears - I checked using the designer view to see my ER diagram which dose not appear to have any relation

I am having a compatibility issues i guess .

Here are my server configs.

> On my localhost

- web server apache 2
- PHP 7.2
- Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Shows webserver version as 7.2

> on my VPS server(centOS)

- web server apache 2
- after running php --version shows 7.2
- Server    version: 10.2.14-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
- On the phpmyadmin    it shows    web server version 5.6.30 (although
  the php version shown    is 7.2 on    my home directory where all my
  laravel app resides)

Is this due to the php version compatibility where phpmyadmin is working on php 5.6 version.

Just cant get it right - hosting on inmotionhosting VPS with cpanel

Update:

Additionally i cross checked the sql from localhost and live server. Both have distinct or same codes. After migration i can see Constrainsts added in the localhost whereas constraints are not there in live server. Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe because your tables get created as MyISAM and not InnoDB? Without code, we can just guess. Good luck.

Comment: Yes just figured it out. It was the storage engine .. I was using MyISAM for live and InnoDB for local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved : Had to change my engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.